# OpenL Tablets Rule Services is showing "There are no available services" after deploying from the web studio

Tags: java, rule-engine

I followed the installation guide (http://openl-tablets.org/files/openl-tablets/5.17.0/OpenL%20Tablets%20-%20Installation%20Guide.pdf). I have a working webstudio where I could create a project, deploy it to production etc.

However, when I access the webservice app (on the same host, same tomcat), I only get this message: 'There are no available services'

I tried from the demo(http://demo.openl-tablets.org/webstudio/) Example 2 - Corporate Rating deployment, It is showing in the demo web service (https://demo.openl-tablets.org/webservice/).

But when I try the same from local, my local web service is only showing "There are no available services".